# Regex for no reply from email

Tags: regex, vb.net

Does any one has any idea how can i use a regex to check if an email address has a "no-reply" or "do not reply" or "noreply" pattern in order to automatically avoid to send autoresponders to these addresses ?

Comment: This might help give you some idea how to get started: https://regex101.com/r/oL4iQ6/1.  But you should post what you've attempted.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot . i create a function to do that so and it is ok

Comment: Public Function MatchRegexPattern(Regex As String, Source As String, isCaseSensitive As Boolean) As Boolean
        Dim reg As New Regex(Regex)
        If isCaseSensitive = False Then
            Regex = Regex.ToLower
            Source = Source.ToLower
        End If
        Dim m1 As Match = reg.Match(Source.ToString)
        Dim sResult As String = ""
        Return m1.Success
    End Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I find regex awkward to decipher and maintain (does this comment on my programming ability?)

if you only want to do a straightforward check that an email address contains a string, it might jut be easier to read and maintain this alternative. The important bit being the line:

```
If emailAddress.ToUpper.Contains(noReplyString.ToUpper) Then
```

This just converts both strings to uppercase for the purpose of the comparison so that any case mixing in the two strings becomes irrelevant

I know people will probably flag this as not answering the question completely, but I have to try. Its fairly simplistic, but it's readable and easy to alter as needed. The Form Load event just creates a quick bit of code to test it. You can past this into an empty windows form project and run it. After the two message boxes have been shown and dismissed the project's form window will open - Just the way the code was written for quickness as it's late here :)

```
Public Class Form1
Dim noReplyList As New List (Of String)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    initNoReplyList()
    If emailReplyStatus("noreplycompany@test.com") = True Then MessageBox.Show("REPLY!") Else MessageBox.Show("NOREPLY!")
    If emailReplyStatus("ggno-eplyd@test.com") = False Then MessageBox.Show(" NOREPLY!") Else MessageBox.Show("REPLY!")

End Sub

Private Sub initNoReplyList()
    ' add strings to search for here
    noReplyList.Add("no-reply")
    noReplyList.Add("do_not_reply")
    noReplyList.Add("noreply")
End Sub

Private Function emailReplyStatus(emailAddress As String) As Boolean
    ' presume a reply is ok unless found to be otherwise
    emailReplyStatus = True
    'cycles through each string in the list of noreply possibility comparing them in uppercase to
    'the email address in uppercase. 
    'If there is a match, exit set the email reply status to false and exit the for loop
    For Each noReplyString In noReplyList
        If emailAddress.ToUpper.Contains(noReplyString.ToString.ToUpper) Then
            emailReplyStatus = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```